# Excel VBA: Read specific row from txt file through selected column range

Tags: excel, line, vba

I am new to excel vba scripting. What I need is get LZFmax data.
Measurement Results

```
Band [Hz]   6.3         8.0         10.0        12.5        16.0        20.0        25.0        31.5        40.0        50.0        63.0        80.0        100.0       125.0       160.0       200.0       250.0       315.0       400.0       500.0       630.0       800.0       1000.0      1250.0      1600.0      2000.0      2500.0      3150.0      4000.0      5000.0      6300.0      8000.0      10000.0     12500.0     16000.0     20000.0 

            [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]        [dB]    

LZFmax      88.5        81.9        72.8        71.5        70.3        71.0        75.0        69.9        76.5        86.9        93.4        97.9        93.4        86.7        88.8        99.4        98.0        100.8       103.4       97.6        101.4       96.5        93.3        90.2        88.5        91.2        85.2        86.7        80.9        78.4        79.8        80.3        75.8        68.9        66.9        63.9    

LZFmin      20.0        21.4        22.8        20.1        24.6        24.6        28.7        30.5        32.8        35.0        29.0        35.6        34.5        38.0        39.4        39.0        42.5        40.1        41.9        41.7        43.0        39.2        38.5        37.5        36.7        35.4        34.7        34.8        34.6        34.2        34.7        35.7        36.6        37.5        38.9        40.9    

LZeq        61.8        56.8        46.8        46.7        49.1        55.5        49.4        47.5        56.2        69.0        75.3        79.4        75.2        70.7        72.7        76.7        78.8        79.0        79.2        78.6        81.3        78.5        75.2        70.5        70.9        70.0        67.2        68.2        63.6        62.7        57.5        57.4        53.7        51.8        47.8        53.9
```

**I already have a code:**

```
Public koef_k As Double

Private Sub Open_Click()

Dim myFile As Variant, koef_k As Integer
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
           "Select file")
If myFile = False Then Exit Sub

Open myFile For Input As #1
row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, LineFromFile

LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, vbTab)

Range("C9").Offset(row_number, 0).Value = LineItems(1)

row_number = row_number + 1

Loop

Close #1

End Sub
```

which works for data format like this:

```
Band[Hz]    LZFmax                  
50      51                  
63      58                  
80      60                  
100     61                  
125     63                  
160     65                  
200     66                  
250     69                  
315     73                  
400     67                  
500     65                  
630     62                  
800     60                  
1000    58                  
1250    55                  
1600    51                  
2000    48                  
2500    42                  
3150    39                  
4000    36
5000    32
```

How to modify this code that it will read only LZFmax line and go through Band [Hz] columns from 50 to 5000Hz?

**Currently I found partial solution**

```
Private Sub Open_Click()
    Dim fn As Variant, myLine As Long, txt As String, i As Integer, x
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
           "Open File")
    If fn = False Then Exit Sub
    myLine = 111 '<- change to suite
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
    x = Split(txt, vbTab)
    'MsgBox x(myLine + 1)
    row_number = 0
    Range("C9").Offset(row_number, 0).Value = x(myLine - 10)
    i = 10
    Do While i < 31
    Cells(i, "C").Value = x(myLine)
    i = i + 1
    myLine = myLine + 1
    Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

This code works as I want, only  myLine value is not very handy, because I had to find it manually.
Maybe there is a better way to optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

So i took your raw data as input, had to modify it a bit for me to get it to work. I fixed some things and ended up with this code:

```
Private Sub Open_Click()
    Dim fn As Variant, myLine As Long, txt As String
    Dim i As Integer, x As Variant, y As Variant, z As Variant, c As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Tabelle1") 'EDIT
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
           "Open File")
    If fn = False Then Exit Sub
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
    x = Split(txt, vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        If Left(x(i), 4) = "Band" Then
            y = x(i)
        ElseIf Left(x(i), 6) = "LZFmax" Then
            z = x(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    y = Replace(y, "  ", " ")
    y = Split(y, " ")
    z = Replace(z, "  ", " ")
    z = Split(z, " ")
    c = 2
    For i = 0 To UBound(y)
        If y(i) <> "" And y(i) <> "[Hz]" And y(i) <> "Band" Then
            sht.Cells(c, 3).Value = y(i)
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next i
    c = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(z)
        If z(i) <> "" Then
            sht.Cells(c, 4).Value = z(i)
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next i
    sht.Range("C1").Value = "Band [Hz]"
Close #1
End Sub
```

Im not sure, how you planned to arrange the data in excel, but i just printed the scale and the data in two columns. Its searches in the textfile for the right lines (cut the first letter of each line and compares) and arranges the data in two arrays (not one because of the formatting, they have different lenghts) and print them out. The header of the first line was seperated into two elements so i ignored them and added the header for it later, to make it not that ugly. Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. There is a code part which is not fully clear for me.
`x = Split(txt, vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        If Left(x(i), 4) = "Band" Then
            y = x(i)
        ElseIf Left(x(i), 6) = "LZFmax" Then
            z = x(i)
            Exit For
        End If`


So vbLine option in split, splits entire file into lines and 
numbers 4 and 6 are for checking if Band and LZF is in those lines ?

Comment: Yes `vbNewLine` splits the txt file into 9 Lines, the array `x` now contains 9 Elements. Now im going through each line and cutting the first 4(6) letters to see if they either `Band`or `LZFmax`. But its just like you said. If you have any other question, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Following should give you desired result.

```
Sub GetDataFromFile()
    Dim colIndex As Long
    Dim LineText As String
    Dim bandArr, LZFMaxArr, arr
    Dim fn As Variant
    'Open "C:\Users\Shiva\Desktop\t1.txt" For Input As #24
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt", , _
           "Open File")
    If fn = False Then Exit Sub
    Open fn For Input As #24
    colIndex = 1
    While Not EOF(24)
        Line Input #24, LineText
            If colIndex = 1 Then 'condition for Band Column
                arr = Split(CStr(LineText), " ")
                bandArr = GetArray(arr)
            ElseIf colIndex = 5 Then 'condition for LZFMax Column
                arr = Split(CStr(LineText), " ")
                LZFMaxArr = GetArray(arr)
            End If
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
    Wend
    Close #24

    Dim rIndex As Long
    rIndex = 2
    'display headers
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = bandArr(1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = LZFMaxArr(1)
    'display column value where 50<=Band<=5000
    For j = 2 To UBound(bandArr)
        If bandArr(j) >= 50 And bandArr(j) <= 5000 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(rIndex, 1).Value = bandArr(j)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(rIndex, 2).Value = LZFMaxArr(j)
            rIndex = rIndex + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub

Private Function GetArray(arr As Variant)
    Dim destArr(), tempArr() As String
    Dim rowIndex, index As Long
    Dim temp As String
    temp = ""
    rowIndex = 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not arr(j - 1) = vbNullString Then
            'add column values in a atring
            temp = temp & "," & arr(j - 1)
        End If
    Next j
    tempArr = Split(temp, ",")

    ReDim destArr(LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr))
    For index = LBound(tempArr) To UBound(tempArr)
        'assign comma separated values to array
        destArr(index) = tempArr(index)
    Next index

    GetArray = destArr
End Function
```

This is the output I get from above code.

[image]

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thank You very much. I tested this code and it works. But sometimes measurement device adds extra lines describing setup, before measurement results. 
So this part of code is responsible for looking my required data ?
 `If colIndex = 1 Then 'condition for Band Column
                arr = Split(CStr(LineText), " ")
                bandArr = GetArray(arr)
            ElseIf colIndex = 5 Then 'condition for LZFMax Column`

Comment: Sometimes data might look like this:
`# Hardware Configuration

 Device Info:     XL2, SNo. A2A-09994-E0, FW3.10

 Mic Type:        NTi Audio M4260, SNo. 5396, Factory adjusted 

 Mic Sensitivity: 32.0 mV/Pa

 Time Zone:       UTC+01:00 (Europe/Berlin)

 Band [Hz] 6.3      8.0      10.0     12.5     16.0     20.0     25.0     31.5     40.0     50.0     63.0     80.0     100.0    125.0    160.0    200.0    250.0    315.0    400.0    500.0    630.0    800.0    1000.0   1250.0   1600.0   2000.0   2500.0   3150.0   4000.0   5000.0   6300.0   8000.0   10000.0  12500.0`

Comment: So what I need to do is setup correctly colIndex values right?

Comment: `Band` and `[Hz]`are stored in 2 Elements so `LZFmax` Values are one index higher. It should be `ActiveSheet.Cells(rIndex, 2).Value = LZFMaxArr(j - 1)`. I dont know how it worked for you  with the decimal comparison that you get this output but i need to use `If bandArr(j) >= 500 And bandArr(j) <= 50000 Then` . Excel is weired sometimes.

Comment: Well I changed index values, opened file in notepad++ to see exact lines. It works. But data filled in excel cells has strange format, it has additional tab. So excel cant plot graphs or calculate